# chaining appendTo method to animate is not working?

Tags: jquery

chaining appendTo to the animate is not working? Meaning the left margin never moves over to margin 0 from margin 600px?

```
    $(data).filter('.test1Div').appendTo("#tes1Section").animate({"left": + slideLeft},"slow");
```

I can see the data get inserted into the #test1Section because I manually move the test1Section div over..

Comment: [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) please. Simply not enough information to go on right now. Perhaps make a minimal example on http://jsfiddle.net.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason you need to append the element after the animation is started, like so:

```
$(data).filter('.test1Div').animate({left: slideLeft},"slow").appendTo("#tes1Section");
```

Pay notice to how the animate function is written, and do as landons said, make sure you have your elements names correct.

**Edit:** Just noticed that you are writing "left margin", but you do know that you are currently animating the css "left" property, and not the css "marginLeft" property?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing a "t" in appendTo('#tes**t**1Section').  Beyond that, make sure your test1Div has a position of relative or absolute.